# how to speed up android studio build time in my project

Tags: android, build, android-studio

I have 5 modules in my project, it takes me 2 mins to build everytime, is there any way to speed up android studio build time?

Comment: for me,
open Settings --> choose Gradle --> then select Offline work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add this in your build.gradle file inside the android closure

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}
```

It will allocate large heap size for your dex process which usually takes more time in build.
You can change your your heap size according to RAM you have in your system like "2048M" for 2GB allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea might be using a faster repository. If your build is using `mavenCentral()` try to replace it with `jcenter()`.

Comment: jcenter() is deprecated. Does this create a problem?

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the following two properties to the "gradle.properties" file in the project root improved performance considerably.

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

"org.gradle.parallel=true" does parallel processing of the modules.  You may receive a message that the feature is experimental but it has worked for me without any problems.

"org.gradle.daemon=true" will keep a dedicated Gradle JVM running so that it is not re-started each time you do a build.  This first build takes as long but subsequent builds are much quicker.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can speed up android studio build time.
1. You need to clean your project before building your project.
2. Close all other projects on which you are not working before build.
3. Allow auto build option.

Answer (score 0):

According to this document https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#dev-build

If you are using `MultiDexApplication` you can set `minSdkVersion 21` for your `develop productFlavors` to mitigate the longer build times for multidex output.

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
}
```